# NVIDIA Dual GPU Driver Issue

Tags: gpu, display-driver, nvidia, dual-gpu

Hope someone can help.

I needed more graphics card ports because I want 4 screens.
My main GPU is a Nvidia GTX 1650 Super
I recently purchased a cheap second GPU (Nvidia GT710) thinking I can just stick it on my motherboard and all will be sweet. (Sounds like I made a mistake here).
I am not expecting anything flash from the GT710 (Just watching Youtube and Excel etc.)

Here's the problem: Firstly, when I booted , the second card didn't pick up a screen so I messed with the drivers and downloaded the driver for the GT710. This looks like it's a very old driver (2020) or something. Now all screens started working but the same 2020 driver was also applied to my GTX 1650 Super which made it really slow and can't play games or antyhing on it anymore. Whenever I try to install a newer driver, the GT710 just stops working completely.

I've tried different things like Manually installing the driver for each card but Windows just takes that driver and applies to both cards.

I'm wondering if there's a way to hard force the driver to use in the registry ? anyone ever tried that? From what I'm reading, peeople say it's a Nvidia problem and I should probably have bought a AMD card for my second GPU.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

In the post
[Intalling two different GPUs and their drivers](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/intalling-two-different-gpus-and-thier-drivers/47726)
The explanation was that it's better not to install the drivers for
the two cards at the same time.

The process that worked for at least two users was as follows :

> - Initial boot up the computer
> - Restart
> - Uninstal drivers for both. Windows 10 will have auto installed a bad driver for the 960.
> - Download the GeForce Experience tool.
> - Restart.The tool won’t recognize your drivers yet
> - Install the drivers using the tool
> - Restart
> - Use the tool and install again. It will install additional items.
> - Restart
> - At this point the GPUs had no issues when I viewed them in device
>   management.

Comment: This is unlikely to solve the issue. The main problem is the user must have the legacy branch driver for the legacy card and that one doesn't support correctly the newer card. This is and will always be a problem when mixing cards of many generations apart, Nvidia or AMD.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I'm not in a situation to test the above, but it's claimed that with this procedure one can have different drivers for the two cards. If it doesn't work, this answer will be deleted.

Comment: In your link the cards in question are GTX1070 and GTX980 that are supported by the same (and current) driver version unlike the legacy 710 the OP has.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: For the author of that post, it apparently didn't work like that (remember his driver dated from 2017). Also the poster of the answer claimed that it worked for him. I'll wait and see if it works for the poster, or not. Otherwise I don't see much hope for a solution for our poster.